# How can I stop a printer from printing in python/tkinter? I can't do it by pressing the button2 and using the function stop_printing

Tags: python, tkinter, printing

```
#this code creates an interface to generate barcodes with a selected printer 
   import barcode
    import win32api
    import os
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import ttk
    from tkinter import font as tkFont
    import win32api
    import win32print
    import win32ui
    from glob import glob
    from PIL import Image, ImageWin
    from barcode.base import Barcode
    from barcode.writer import ImageWriter
    import sys
    
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Barcode Printer Sowtware".center(425))
    root.configure(background='#2596be')


    frame1 = LabelFrame(root,text="Impostazione della stampa del codice",width=800, height=180,bg='#2596be',
                        highlightbackground='white',highlightcolor='white',font=("TkDefaultFont",24))
    frame1.pack(padx=60,pady=60)
    frame1.grid_propagate(0)
    
    label1 = Label(frame1, text="Tipo di carta",bg='#2596be',font=("TkDefaultFont",18)).grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W)
    label2 = Label(frame1, text="Tipo di stampa",bg='#2596be',font=("TkDefaultFont",18)).grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W)
    label3 = Label(frame1, text="Tipo del codice di barre",bg='#2596be',font=("TkDefaultFont",18)).grid(row=4,column=0,sticky=W)
    label4 = Label(frame1, text="Nome della stampante in uso",bg='#2596be',font=("TkDefaultFont",18)).grid(row=6,column=0,sticky=W)
    
    
    label1_1 = Label(frame1, text="        ",bg='#2596be',font=("TkDefaultFont",18)).grid(row=0,column=1)
    #label2_1 = Label(frame1, text="                                ",bg='#2596be',font=("TkDefaultFont",18)).grid(row=2,column=1,sticky=W)
    #label3_1 = Label(frame1, text="                                ",bg='#2596be',font=("TkDefaultFont",18)).grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=W)
    #label4_1 = Label(frame1, text="                                ",bg='#2596be',font=("TkDefaultFont",18)).grid(row=2,column=1,sticky=W)
    
    
    
    paper_types = ["                          ","Rotolo di etichette doppio"]
    
    var1 = StringVar()
    var1.set(paper_types[0])
    style = ttk.Style()
    style.theme_use('clam')
    style.configure('my.TMenubutton', font=('TkDefaultFont', 12),borderwidth=1, background='white',width=30) 
    drop1 = ttk.OptionMenu(frame1, var1, *paper_types,style='my.TMenubutton')
    drop1.grid(row=0,column=2)
    
    printing_types = ["                          ","Serie unica", "Serie 2 etichette uguali","Serie 3 etichette uguali","Serie 4 etichette uguali"]
    
    var2 = StringVar()
    var2.set(printing_types[0])
    drop2 = ttk.OptionMenu(frame1, var2, *printing_types,style='my.TMenubutton')
    drop2.grid(row=2,column=2)
    
    barcodes_types = ["                          ","Codice con numero","Codice senza numero","Codice con numero criptato"]
    
    
    var3 = StringVar()
    #var3.set(barcodes_types[0])
    drop3 = ttk.OptionMenu(frame1, var3, *barcodes_types,style='my.TMenubutton')
    drop3.grid(row=4,column=2)
    
    
    all_printers = [printer[2] for printer in win32print.EnumPrinters(2)]    
    
    var4 = StringVar()
    var4.set(all_printers[0])
    drop4 = ttk.OptionMenu(frame1, var4,"                          ", *all_printers,style='my.TMenubutton')
    drop4.grid(row=6,column=2)
    
    
    frame2 = LabelFrame(root,text="Parametri del codice",width=800, height=125,bg='#2596be',
                        highlightbackground='white',highlightcolor='white',font=("TkDefaultFont",24))
    frame2.pack(padx=36,pady=36)
    frame2.grid_propagate(0)
    
    label5 = Label(frame2, text="Da numero",bg='#2596be',font=("TkDefaultFont",18)).grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W)
    label6 = Label(frame2, text="Ripetizione X",bg='#2596be',font=("TkDefaultFont",18)).grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W)
    
    label5_1 = Label(frame2, text="                                 ",bg='#2596be',font=("TkDefaultFont",18)).grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=W)
    label6_1 = Label(frame2, text="                                 ",bg='#2596be',font=("TkDefaultFont",18)).grid(row=2,column=1,sticky=W)
    
    entry5 = Entry(frame2,width=33,bd=2,font=('TkDefaultFont', 12))
    entry6 = Entry(frame2,width=33,bd=2,font=('TkDefaultFont', 12))
    entry5.grid(row=0,column=2,sticky=E,ipady=8)
    entry6.grid(row=2,column=2,sticky=E,ipady=8)
    
    frame3 = LabelFrame(root,text="Stampante in disposizione",width=800, height=80,bg='#2596be',
                        highlightbackground='white',highlightcolor='white',font=("TkDefaultFont",24))
    frame3.pack(padx=36,pady=36)
    #frame3.grid(row=2,column=1)
    frame3.grid_propagate(0)
    
    label7 = Label(frame3, text="Scegliere stampante",bg='#2596be',font=("TkDefaultFont",18)).grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W)
    label7_1 = Label(frame3, text="                    ",bg='#2596be',font=("TkDefaultFont",18)).grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=W)

    
#this function should stop the printing    
    check_print=True
    def stop_printing(arg):
        return arg
    
#this function print the barcodes
    
    def barcode_printer():
        if ((var3.get()=="Codice con numero")):
            iteration=entry6.get()
            startNumber=entry5.get() 
            for i in range(int(iteration)):
                Barcode.default_writer_options['write_text'] = True
                kr = barcode.get_barcode_class('code39')            
                Kr = kr(str(startNumber),writer=ImageWriter(), add_checksum=False)
                Kr.save("Test{}".format(i))
                startNumber=int(startNumber)+1
                path = os.getcwd()
    
                LOGPIXELSX = 44
                LOGPIXELSY = 42
    
                printer_name = win32print.SetDefaultPrinter(var4.get())
                file_name = path  + '\\Test{}.png'.format(i)
    
                hDC = win32ui.CreateDC ()
                hDC.CreatePrinterDC (printer_name)
                printer_size = hDC.GetDeviceCaps (LOGPIXELSX), hDC.GetDeviceCaps (LOGPIXELSY)
    
                bmp = Image.open (file_name)
                if bmp.size[0] < bmp.size[1]:
                    bmp = bmp.rotate (90)
    
                hDC.StartDoc (file_name)
                hDC.StartPage ()
    
                dib = ImageWin.Dib (bmp)    
                dib.draw (hDC.GetHandleOutput (), (0,0,printer_size[0],printer_size[1]))
    
                hDC.EndPage ()
                hDC.EndDoc ()
                hDC.DeleteDC ()
#this if statement should stop the for loop
                if(stop_printing==False):
                    break
        elif (var3.get()=="Codice senza numero"):
            iteration=entry6.get()
            startNumber=entry5.get()
            for i in range(int(iteration)):
                Barcode.default_writer_options['write_text'] = False
                kr = barcode.Code39
                Kr = kr(str(startNumber),writer=ImageWriter(), add_checksum=False)
                Kr.save("Test{}".format(i))
                startNumber=int(startNumber)+1
                path = os.getcwd()
    
                LOGPIXELSX = 44
                LOGPIXELSY = 42
    
                printer_name = win32print.SetDefaultPrinter(var4.get())
                file_name = path  + '\\Test{}.png'.format(i)
    
                hDC = win32ui.CreateDC ()
                hDC.CreatePrinterDC (printer_name)
                printer_size = hDC.GetDeviceCaps (LOGPIXELSX), hDC.GetDeviceCaps (LOGPIXELSY)
    
                bmp = Image.open (file_name)
                if bmp.size[0] < bmp.size[1]:
                    bmp = bmp.rotate (90)
    
                hDC.StartDoc (file_name)
                hDC.StartPage ()
    
                dib = ImageWin.Dib (bmp)
                #Introduci a for loop per stampare lo stesso barcode nella stessa pagina eventualmente,
                #vedi prima funzionamento con la stampante dei barcode!
                dib.draw (hDC.GetHandleOutput (), (0,0,printer_size[0],printer_size[1]))
    
                hDC.EndPage ()
                hDC.EndDoc ()
                hDC.DeleteDC ()
#this if statement should stop the for loop
                if(stop_printing==False):
                    break
#clicking this button starts printing
    button1 = Button(root, text="Stampa",height=2, width=6,command = barcode_printer, font=("TkDefaultFont",18),bg='white')
#clicking this button should stop printing
    button2 = Button(root, text="Termina",height=2, width=6,command=lambda *args: stop_printing(False), font=("TkDefaultFont",18),bg='white')
    button1.pack()
    button2.pack()
    root.state('zoomed')
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Tkinter will be unresponsive during the loop and that's why your architecture fails. You need parallel execution of code, separate your *data handles* from your GUI e.g. in separated threads. Then you can use a button to interfere the *data thread*.

Comment: Another way and maybe easier way to implement this behaviour could be to use `.after(ms, function, argument)` to mimic a loop and set a flag to your *co-routine*.